# SoundEffect.DistanceScale - how to calculate scale in 2D?

Tags: c#, .net, xna, monogame

I have a 2D MonoGame game that uses sound effects. I'm trying to calculate the most appropriate scale to use in SoundEffect.DistanceScale.

```
        SoundEffect.DistanceScale = 50;
```

SoundEffect.DistanceScale controls how much a sound effect changes volume as the listener moves further away. The listener is positioned in the center of the camera, and the emitters are located around the game world.

I don't know how best to calculate the scale, based on the world rect (8000 * 8000) and the camera rect (say 1920* 1080, including zoom). Any guidance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Since you (probably) have the position of the sound source and the position of the player you should be able to get the scale by using Vector2.Distance() for those two positions.

Comment: @PavelSlesinger how will this work for multiple emitters? SoundEffect.DistanceScale is a one size fits all value for all sound effects.